# Export 2D outline to DXF

Tags: export, 2d

I am trying to use blender to create 2d cut files for my CNC Plasma table.  I imported some simple DXF outlines made some changes and converted it to a mesh. However every time I try to export it out it does nothing.  I have tried changing settings but nothing still happens.
Has anyone tired to generate a cut file on here and had these problems?